# Java 9 not compiling

Tags: java, compilation, java-9

I want to start using Java 9 and 10, but when I make a simple class with this code:

```
package jav;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainTester9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List list1 = List.of();
        List list2 = List.of("one","two","three");

    }
}
```

I get the error "The method of() is undefined for the type List".
In Eclipse, I've got the jre 10 in the installed JREs, and the Compiler compliance level is 10. (I've tried the same with 9 too).
Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

But it's not an eclipse problem, cause in the command line "java --version" returns "java 10.0.1 2018-04-17", but javac gives me "Cannot find symbol" in the position of the "of"s.

Comment: The path? You mean C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1 that's referred to in the installed JREs?

Comment: Not just checking the installed JREs, but also you need to check against your project settings and make sure JRE-9 or 10 is used by your project as the compilation JRE.

Comment: Look at the import statements.  Have you imported the correct `List`?

Comment: Rightclick on project --> Properties --> Java Compiler --> Enable project specific settings is not ticked.

I import java.util.List;

Comment: You say java --version returns 10.0.1, what does javac -version return? Could you post the complete sample file? It doesn't look like it will be big.

Comment: Posted the file and, oh, you're right. javac -version returns javac 1.8.0_71. I didn't know those two could be on different versions. But how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It worked now. Here's what I had to do, apart from the things mentioned in the comments above:

To make it work on the command line: change the environment variable (called JAVA_HOME in my case, as most people call it, and found in the PATH)

In Eclipse:
Project --> Properties --> Java Compiler --> Check "Enable project specific settings" --> set JDK Compliance to 10 (Not sure if this step was necessary)

Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Remove jre-1.8 from Classpath and add jdk-10.0.1